# Axios POST method with React shows as Anonymous user and CORS error in Django Backend

Tags: reactjs, django, post, django-cors-headers

I have been succesfully using GET methods with Axios while the logged in user information is succesfully transmitted to backend with the following code :

```
await axios({
      method: 'get',
      url: BASE_BACKEND_URL + `/project/` + project_uuid + `/`,
      data: {},
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream' },
      withCredentials: true,
    })
```

---

```
class ProjectView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, uuid):
        logging.info("ProjectManifest GET begin")
        user            = request.user
        print(user)
```

When I use a similar code with the POST API call of the same function, Django backend shows the request has been requested by an anonymous user instead of the logged in user.

The code for the POST command is below:

```
await axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: BASE_BACKEND_URL + '/project/' + project_uuid + '/',
      data: { project_uuid : projectJSON },
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', },
      withCredentials: true,
    })
```

---

```
class ProjectView(APIView):
    def post(self, request, uuid):
        logging.info(f"ProjectManifest POST begin: {request.user}")
```

How can I make the react axios post call to work properly with Django backend ?